Relation between Abelian rings and McCoy rings
First, some basic definitions:
Abelian ring : A ring $R$ is said to be abelian if its every idempotent is central.
Armendariz ring :  A ring $R$ is said to be Armendariz if whenever $$f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $a_ib_j=0,\forall 0\leq i \leq n, 0\leq j \leq m $, where $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=m}b_jx^j$.
McCoy ring: A ring $R$ is said to be McCoy if whenever $$f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $a_ir=0$ and $sb_j=0,\forall 0\leq i \leq n, 0\leq j \leq m $, and for some nonzero $r,s\in R$ where $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}a_ix^i$ and $g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{j=m}b_jx^j$.
Now we know that all Armendariz rings are abelian and also all Armendariz rings are McCoy. So what is the relation between Abelian and McCoy?


Camillo, Victor, and Pace P. Nielsen. "McCoy rings and zero-divisors." Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra 212.3 (2008): 599-615.

Theorem 7.1. There exists a McCoy ring with 1 which is not Abelian.

Nielsen, Pace P. "Semi-commutativity and the McCoy condition." Journal of Algebra 298.1 (2006): 134-141.

Section 3 p. 138 gives an example of an Abelian ring that is not McCoy on a side.
I found the second one using DaRT, but there was no conclusive example for the first one, so I thank you for asking this question.

Before asking the question, I also searched on DaRT, but didn't find

After not finding anything on DaRT, my google search for "mccoy ring that is not abelian" had your question as the first hit, and the paper i cite above as the second.

SEO on this site is crazy.
